# php не загружает большие файлы

Tags: php, yii2

Мне необходимо загружать файлы с размером ~2гб. На данный момент чтобы я не делал, больше 100мб загрузить не могу. Указывал настройки php.ini на локалке, на хостинге, на виртуальном сервере. Нигде не работает.

Настройки php.ini:

```
file_uploads = On
max_execution_time = 7200
max_input_time = 7200
memory_limit = 128M
upload_max_filesize = 2047M
post_max_size = 2047M
```

Указываю `set_time_limit(0);`, но это так же не исправляет ситуацию.

На локалке сразу выдает `ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED`.

На виртуально сервере, то пытается грузить то нет, в итоге выдает `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`.

EDIT: При загрузке на виртуальном сервере, увидел строку снизу, где браузер указывает кол-во процентов загрузки. Постоянно доходит до 38% и сбрасывается (конечно зависимо от размера файла)

EDIT2: Методом вычисления понял, что на виртуальном сервере принимает файлы не больше чем ~343мб

Comment: может быть еще ограничение web-сервера на таймаут. Смотрите логи веб-сервера, что конкретно произошло

Comment: Какой сервер используется? Каким способом обрабатывается php в сервере? fast-cgi, fcgid, php-cgi, php-fpm? Тут много узких мест может быть. Опять же, может у вас на сервере тупо памяти не хватает

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Я определенно слаб в таких вещах. Знаю что сервер используется Apache в связке с Nginx, а каким способом обрабатывается php на vestacp найти не смог. Думаю по умолчанию.

Comment: @DmitryKozlov В итоге обнаружил ошибку в логах `PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Загрузка очень больших файлов на сервер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877351/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все заработало когда  указал:

В `httpd.conf`:

```
Timeout 7200
```

В `nginx.conf`:

```
client_max_body_size 2047m;
```

P.S. Регулируя `client_max_body_size` в `nginx.conf` и `upload_max_filesize` с `post_max_size` в `php.ini`, можно загружать файлы какие в разы превышают размер оперативной памяти. При этом не обязательно `memory_limit` в `php.ini` указывать такого же размера.

Answer (score 2):

Читайте документацию внимательнее:

> http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize
>
> Устанавливает максимально допустимый размер данных, отправляемых
> методом POST. Это значение также влияет на загрузку файлов. Для
> загрузки больших файлов это значение должно быть больше значения
> директивы upload_max_filesize. В сущности, memory_limit должна быть
> больше чем post_max_size.

В `.htaccess`:

```
php_flag post_max_size 1G
php_flag memory_limit 2G
php_flag upload_max_filesize 1G
```

PHP спокойно скушал полуторагиговое видео, код примерно такой:

```
$source = $file_info['tempname'];
$destination = self::getRealStoragePath($file_info) . '/' . $file_info['internal_name'];
$success = move_uploaded_file($source, $destination);
return $success ? $file_info : NULL;
```

Comment: Забавно, но в прошлом вопросе мне доказывали обратное.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877351/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80

Comment: Доверяйте, но проверяйте. 
Я, прежде чем писать ответ, пошел на свой сервер и проверил :) 

> Total time: 149.3651 sec, Memory Used (current): 389704 , Memory Used (max): 397160

Результат загрузки полутогигового видео в локалке. 
В `.htaccess`: 
php_flag post_max_size 1G
php_flag memory_limit 2G
php_flag upload_max_filesize 1G

Comment: Не знаю, можно ли тут отмечать ответ решением, но если это решение - отметьте пожалуйста (P.S. wow, wow, какая аватарка)

Comment: Извиняюсь за ожидание, проверял у себя. Я очевидно что-то не так делаю, так как при добавлении ваших строк в .htaccess, сразу вылетает `HTTP ERROR 500`.

Comment: Если без строк в .htaccess, то к сожалению изменение параметра `memory_limit` ничего не меняет.

Comment: Интересное кино. Сразу? А что в логах веб-сервера (что там у вас, апач? энжинкс?) и самого PHP?

Comment: Добавил отображение ошибок и ваш код .htaccess все таки через раз работает с вашим кодом. И в логах нашел ошибку `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8192 bytes)`. Дело в том, что на локалке когда добавляю код, всегда `HTTP ERROR 500`, а на виртуалке кое-как работает:)

Comment: Сделайте `memory_limit ` на 50% больше `upload_max_filesize`
Может быть, у вас на самом сервере памяти физически не хватает (даже с учетом свопа)

P.S. Выше вы там написали "vestacp". Я такое не использую, у меня все работает ;-)

Comment: Что-то бред какой-то, что не ставлю уже вообще работать не хочет, вижу только `PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 266240 bytes)`

Comment: Возможно и памяти не хватает, на виртуалке 1гб оперативки. А как мне тогда загрузить файл такого размера?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82909/discussion-between-arris-and-vlad-panchenko).